# How to render Dynamic Tabs and its content in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, redux, tabs

I need to render dynamic tabs and load a switch component based on the data I am getting from firebase.

My Object looks like this

```
{
  "Bed Room": "DI7RACPv",
  "BedRoom": "87hashd",
  "Kitchen": "PZifopFg",
  "Living Room": "6VnNdKZ8"
}
```

The key should be the Title of the **Tabs** and the value of the key could be used for displaying my **switch components**. Is there any way how I can do it in react-native

**IMAGE REPRESENTATION**

[image: Image Representation]

Answer (score 1):

May this help you. This is not the best way, but it's clear enough to solve your problem.

```
const object = {
  'Bed Room': 'DI7RACPv',
  'BedRoom': '87hashd',
  'Kitchen': 'PZifopFg',
  'Living Room': '6VnNdKZ8',
};

const [selectedTabIndex, setselectedTabIndex] = useState(0);

return (
  <View>
    {/* Render list of tabs */}
    {Object.keys(object).map((title, index) => (
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={{
          backgroundColor: selectedTabIndex === index ? 'blue' : 'white',
        }}
        onPress={() => setselectedTabIndex(index)}>
        <Text>{title}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    ))}

    {/* Render content of the selected tabs */}
    <View>
      <Text>{Object.values(object)[selectedTabIndex]}</Text>
    </View>
  </View>
);
```